# TimeSpan? = DateTime?.Value - DateTime?.Value results in null

Tags: c#

My `DateTime?` with a value minus another `DateTime?` with a value is resulting in a null `TimeSpan?`.

[image]

***See the date values have been pinned to the debugger.***

I could not replicate this in a console app as it worked with the same dates. The date formats are in dd/mm/yyyy

I understand that I do not need `.Value` with the code in places. I have tried without `.Value`.

**Post-Edit**

```
TimeSpan ts = DateModified.Value - publishRecord.DatePublished.Value;
TimeSpan ts2 = DateModified.Value.Subtract(publishRecord.DatePublished.Value);
TimeSpan? ts3 = DateModified - publishRecord.DatePublished;
```

All attempts result in that line having the exception as in the screenshot. `Nullable object must have a value.`

*... continuing to dig as per suggestions and show more information as requested...*

**Post-Edit 2:**

Both DateModified and DatePublished are DateTime? standard. The properties are auto get; set;

**Post-Edit 3 - Summary**

I can't explain this bug. This is a system that is nunit tested. So it is a surprise when something in a well tested area turns this up. This bug appeared during interface development and so was debugging it by attaching to the class library and refreshing the web page. Builds in both solutions were always performed.

I make regular database snapshots and retained the current broken one while going back to a snapshot just prior to the problem. The system worked. Going back to the broken one showed the bug again.

I made a console app and wrote code with the class library reference to perform a similar code track and could not replicate the bug in the "broken" snapshot.

What happened in between working and not working, windows updates, mainly for office software. *Missed a coffee break.*

I have retained the database snapshot and will see if this problem occurs again in the next few days. If it does not I will at that point delete the question.

**Thank you to everyone for your attention and suggestions.**

Comment: If you use `.Value` then you need `TimeSpan` not `TimeSpan?`

Comment: That shouldn't be possible... Are `DateModified` and/or `DatePublished` perhaps properties that for some reason don't always return the same value? You could store `DateModified.Value` and `DatePublished.Value` in local variables, and then subtract from those, to verify that they were non-null when you read them.

Comment: Why do you use __nullable__ `Timespan?` in this case? I assume the `DateModified` and `publishRecord.DatePublished` are nullable `DateTime?` instances. If so, by using the `.Value` you unwrap the underlying __non-nullable__ `DateTime` instance. The `ts` will then not have to be nullable. Perhaps you receive an error somewhere else? Are `publishRecord.DatePublished` and `DateModified` guaranteed not to be null?

Comment: Did you try `TimeSpan ts = DateModified.Value.Subtract(publishRecord.DatePublished.Value)`?

Comment: There might be something more going on here. Can you post a bigger code snippet, which includes initialization of both date time fields?

Comment: Have you tried *debugging* to ensure that both DateTimes actually have values or are you just assuming that they do?

Comment: Did you create own `DateTime` class? I don't see other way to have such problem given your code.

Comment: @AntP: They have values, see the watches i set in the screenshot.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov: Stock standard DateTime struct

Comment: @IvayloSlavov: Both variables are `true` to `HasValue`

Comment: @Jcl: Tried that without success (`.Subtract()`) - updated post

Comment: My suspicion, there is something wrong with your debug code and it halts on the wrong line and the actual Null exception is from one of the dates.

Comment: @IvayloSlavov: I have pinned the date values in the screenshot. They are days away from each other. My TimeSpan is null, so .Duration() wont help.

Comment: @Magnus: both datetimes have a value as I have displayed in the screenshot.

Comment: @IvayloSlavov: Both are auto properties. Their values are `get` as they are.

Comment: How about showing us the stack dump.

Comment: Ok, the last thing I can assume is that you have some compile error in your latest code, and when debugging, the debugger shows the latest written code, but runs a previously compiled code (then wrongly matching the source code lines). This can show you an  exception on a wrong place. Are you sure the latest code is compiled and you are debugging __that__ code? Or maybe you can compile everything allright, but you do not have direct dependencies and your application is resolving earlier version of something?

Comment: @IvayloSlavov: 100% sure it is the latest code. I have a class library and a web library. I am debugging the class lib and refreshing the web page. I do get warning if I do that without building first. Not ideal, all my tests are green, and hate doing it this way.

Comment: @Valamas-AUS, I know you used auto properties, but do these belong to an __entity__? In some __ORMs__ entities are actually __proxies to some compiler-generated implementation__, that could __rewrite__ your properties in a way, so it would establish a database connection and evaluate them based on a db query. Are you certain this is not your case? It would explain your issue, and __especially__ the fact you are being unable to reproduce it in a console app.

Comment: I'm wondering related to what Ivaylo is saying whether putting a `DateTime d1 = DateModified.Value` and likewise for d2 (note: not-nullable) to properly check that what you have out are real DateTime objects with appropriate data in them and then doing `TimeSpan ts = d1-d2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in using a Nullable Timespan here in that way. Either both of the DateTime?'s have a value, and you get a regular (non-nullable) TimeSpan, or one or both of the DateTime?'s does not have a value, in which case access the `.Value` property will cause an exception. It sounds like you should have code more like this:

```
TimeSpan? ts = null;
if (DateModified.HasValue && publishRecord.DatePublished.HasValue)
   ts = DateModified.Value - publishRecord.DatePublished.Value;
```

I also noticed this:

> I made a console app and wrote code with the class library reference to perform a similar code track and could not replicate the bug in the "broken" snapshot.

Based on that, I'd look for something in another thread that's changing one of those values out from under you. Perhaps try logging the values of `DateModified` and `publishRecord.DatePublished` before the line executes and again when the exception is thrown. I expect you'll find that one of them has become `null`.

Comment: I tried your code. The debugger steps into that if statement. However, the result `ts` is null. Implementing logging now.

Comment: Debugger is reporting `DateModified.HasValue == true`. Log file is reporting `false`. However, conditional breakpoint hit `!DateModified.HasValue` while watch or hover over value says `true`.

Comment: I even tried `var dateModified = DateTime.Parse(DateModified.Value.ToLongDateString());` and it came up with the same nullable error message. I am going with your threading theory, even though I can't pin point it yet.

Comment: I have searched every database record and none have a null DateModified (since datemodified is set with datecreated)

Comment: While the debugger did not show it. The problem was an entity not triggering self loading on the DateModified field. We have a property `ShouldLoadFromDB` which was true found via logging.

Comment: ... the ghost object was not loaded when DateModified was accessed. We have rectified that.